# Trying to use Docker with Django but server not starting

Tags: django, docker

I'm trying to start a Django app using Docker on Windows 10. I'm following the Quickstart Tutorial here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database

When it gets to the `docker-compose up` part, to actually start the app, it gets stuck.

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
 FROM python:3.5
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

when I use `docker-compose up` it gets stuck in:

```
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

Comment: how do you know it gets stuck? Maybe that's the regular output

Comment: I know because the server doesn't respond on the browser.

Comment: add the flag -d

Comment: to the 'docker-compose up' command? like this 'docker-compose up -d'

Comment: Try logging into the docker container like `docker-compose exec django bash` and see if you can run the server from inside on another port.  If you can't log in, it means that runserver isn't starting properly.  Also, check out the logs like `docker-compose logs -f`

Comment: didn't work, it says the port is already in use. Weird, I don't know why its getting stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across a similar issue, I solved it by running docker on the interface.

It was probably getting stuck because the DB was taking too long to start or something like that.

Comment: running docker on the interface? how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found that it was caused by an error in a `models.py` file.

After I stopped the server last time, I added one Model class (just forgot about it) without running the server. When I started the server the next time, I faced your problem, but searching the web was useless, because I had everything OK with my project settings (which often causes such errors).

Then I mentioned that I didn't apply migrations after the last change, so I ran the command:

```
docker-compose up web python3 manage.py makemigrations
docker-compose up web python3 manage.py migrate
```

and it showed me that there was an error in a new Model declaration.
It caused the server to stop responding. I don't know why it works this way instead of showing an error message in a browser or console, but this is how it is. I fixed it and server began responding. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think I hit a similar issue. I found I needed to add the host ip to ALLOWED_HOSTS in composeexample/settings.py. For example

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'10.122.14.13']
```

Comment: I tried putting ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I found a workaround to run it.

In your Django settings.py change ALLOWED_HOST to
`ALLOWED_HOST = ['*']` so Django will allow every host to access the app.

Finally, when you start your `Docker Quickstart Terminal` it shows you `default machine with IP 192.168.XX.XX`. Run `docker-compose up` and you can find your Django app running on IP: 192.168.XX.XX:8000.

Don't worry `docker-compose up` isn't stuck but it's just not echoing any Django output.